# Create QR Codes by Function or Class

Tags: php, function, qr-code

I'm using QRCode from Google API and I put this code in the function.

Now I want to show two images, for example: Two images with different sizes or datas!

It does not matter if you use class or function, I just want to get different output on the page.

This is code:

```
<?php
function CreateQRCode($data, $size, $logo) {
header('Content-type: image/png');
// Get QR Code image from Google Chart API
// http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes.html
$QR = imagecreatefrompng('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chld=H|1&chs='.$size.'&chl='.urlencode($data));
if($logo !== FALSE){
$logo = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($logo));
$QR_width = imagesx($QR);
$QR_height = imagesy($QR);
$logo_width = imagesx($logo);
$logo_height = imagesy($logo);
// Scale logo to fit in the QR Code
$logo_qr_width = $QR_width/3;
$scale = $logo_width/$logo_qr_width;
$logo_qr_height = $logo_height/$scale;
imagecopyresampled($QR, $logo, $QR_width/3, $QR_height/3, 0, 0, $logo_qr_width, $logo_qr_height, $logo_width, $logo_height);
}

imagepng($QR);
imagedestroy($QR);

}

 CreateQRCode('http://google.com', '200x200', FALSE);
?>
```

Like this:

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJSfp.png)
[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qpnB.png)

Comment: your GD code is pointless. if the google url is spitting out a png, then there is absolutely **NO** point in loading it into GD, just so you can re-compress it into a png again. all you need is `readfile('https://....')`

Comment: @MarcB:
Yes, you are exactly right. But this code is part of the original code. In the original code, to scale logo to fit in the QR Code so I can re-compress it into a png again. However I changed my this code to original code.

Comment: @MarcB: How can I use readfile(), please guide.